# Create extra sum column using one of the table columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table data like this:

```
Product     Value
A           20 
A           30
B           10
A           20
C           15
C           15
```

I need to get the sum based on the `Value` column like:

```
Product     Value     Sum
A           20         70
A           30         70
B           10         10
A           20         70
C           15         30
C           15         30
```

How do I query to create the sum of all A, B and C product still showing all records?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code or SQL writing service. We expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain what you're trying to do and the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll be glad to try to help. New folks have a bit of a pass while being told this, but you've been on here long enough to know better.

Comment: @Utrolig The best way to explain it for me was this way. I actually have an Store Procedure but putting all that and explain it would bring confusion instead of making things easier. If I get to understand how to this, I can implemente a similar solution to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a window function for sum:

```
create table #totalValue
(
[Product] varchar(55),
Value int
)

insert into #totalValue
values
('A',20), 
('A',30),
('B',10),
('A',20),
('C',15),
('C',15)


select 
    Product,
    [Value],
    sum([Value]) over (partition by Product) as [Sum]
from #totalValue
```

This should scale better than a solution that queries the same table twice.

Comment: This is the solution I used. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
select a.product, a.value, b.totalsum
from producttable as a
left join ( select sum(c.value) as totalsum,c.product 
            from producttable as c 
            group by c.product
           ) as b
on a.product = b.product
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Product VARCHAR(20),
  Value INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('A', 20), 
('A', 30),
('B', 10),
('A', 20),
('C', 15),
('C', 15);

SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM T WHERE Product = T1.Product) [Sum]
FROM T T1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+-------+-----+
| Product | Value | Sum |
+---------+-------+-----+
| A       |    20 |  70 |
| A       |    30 |  70 |
| B       |    10 |  10 |
| A       |    20 |  70 |
| C       |    15 |  30 |
| C       |    15 |  30 |
+---------+-------+-----+
```